# Regularity of linearized Monge-Ampere equation

Tags: optimal-transportation

Consider the linearized Monge-Ampere equation $ (p-q)+\nabla\cdot(p\nabla\phi)=0$, where $p$ and $q$ are the density functions of two probability measures, which are supported on a bounded domain $\Omega$. The gradient of its solution $ \nabla \phi$ represents the optimal transport from probability $p$ to $q$ approximately. I am interested in the regularity of the solution $\phi$. In specific, under what regularity conditions on $p$ and $q$, the Sobolev norm $$\|\phi\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}:=\big(\Sigma_{|\alpha|\le k}\|D^{\alpha}\phi\|^p_{L^p(\Omega)}\big)^{1/p}$$ can be upper bounded? Moreover, is it possible to show that the $\nabla^2 \phi$ is also Holder continuous and provide an explicit upper bound for the Holder continuity exponent?

Answer (score 3):

Answers to questions like this (but for the *not linearized* version) can be found under "regularity of Kantorovich potentials". This is due to Brennier's theorem which says that the transport map $\phi$ is related to a Kantorovich potential (basically one of the two Lagrange multipliers of the optimal transport problem) by $u(x) = \phi(x) - \tfrac12\|x\|^2$ (holds for quadratic transport cost).

Some paper that have results on the regularity of these potentials are

> Ma, Xi-Nan, Neil S. Trudinger, and Xu-Jia Wang. "Regularity of potential functions of the optimal transportation problem." Archive for rational mechanics and analysis 177.2 (2005): 151-183.

$\mbox{}$

> Liu, Jiakun, Neil S. Trudinger, and Xu-Jia Wang. "Interior C 2, α regularity for potential functions in optimal transportation." Communications in Partial Differential Equations 35.1 (2009): 165-184.

or

> Liu, Jiakun. "Hölder regularity of optimal mappings in optimal transportation." Calculus of Variations and Partial Differential Equations 34.4 (2009): 435.

Comment: As far as I see, the linearized equation is elliptic in $\phi$ and standard regularity results should give some answer.